# How to configure SSH public key per user?

Tags: authentication, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, openssh

I have an OpenSSH server running and different users can log into it with different privileges.

I know you can enable public key authentication and place all the allowed public keys in the `authorized_keys` file. But that only restricts which hosts can log in.

I would like to configure public key authentication so that logging in as `user1` would require a different key compared to logging in as `user2`.

Is there a way to achieve this using OpenSSH?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about public key authentication. Each user on the server has their own authorized_keys file, so by adding a public key to one user, you allow someone with the corresponding private key to log in, as that user. Therefore if you add a public key to user1's authorized_keys file, but not to user2's, the holder of the corresponding private key will only be able to log in as user1 using it.

Comment: that is true if you have one sshd process running for each user, but if you have only one running? you only have one authorized_keys file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Each user account on the destination machine has their own `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (doesn't necessarily have to have, it might not exist). One `sshd` serves many users.

Comment: Maybe it is not completely clear that the `~` in the path `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` stands for `/home/username/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH actually requires you to configure different keys for different users.

Each user account on the destination machine has its own `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (doesn't necessarily have to have, it might not exist).

Let's assume you have `server` and `client`.

`server` has users set up as follows:

```
/home/srv_user01
                /.ssh/authorized_keys
                        --> contains public key of cli_user01
                                 and public key of cli_user03
/home/srv_user02
                /.ssh/authorized_keys
                        --> empty or non-existing
/home/srv_user03
                /.ssh/authorized_keys
                        --> contains public key of cli_user03
```

`client` has three accounts `cli_user01`, `cli_user02`, and `cli_user03`.

On `client` machine:

- `cli_user01` can execute `ssh srv_user01@server` and login to `server` as `srv_user01`
- `cli_user02` cannot connect to `server` at all
- `cli_user03` can execute:

  - `ssh srv_user01@server` and login to `server` as `srv_user01`, or
  - `ssh srv_user03@server` and login to `server` as `srv_user03`
- no user can connect and login as `srv_user02` on `server`

---

In the example above I used different names on client and server side, but if account name was the same on `client` and `server`, user doesn't have to specify the account name in `ssh` command, thus making the impression of "logging to server". So if I am logged on as `user` on client and execute `ssh server`ーit is the same as `ssh user@server`.

On `server` one `sshd` process listens on port 22 (default) and receives connections from each of the connecting users.